# Rename entries in fasta/fastq files in UNIX

Tags: bash, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I have fasta file with x reads and I want to rename the ids of each read.
My file is as follow:

```
>e855552f-9484-4674-8fc4-d9b1f1add023 runid=4140cbe7f7cd36a17a00b732f27dd37bd09e4380 sampleid=mariposas read=55861 ch=2 start_time=2022-11-23T17:43:40Z model_version_id=2021-05-17_dna_r9.4.1_minion_768_2f1c8637 barcode=barcode06
GCTTTAACATTTAGCTATTTATGACACAGTGAAATAAAAGTAATATCTTTTTATTTTTAATTGTATTTATTAGTTACATGTTTTCACATGCATTTAACATAAATGTGATAATTTATGGGAATTACACTACTGTCAAAGTAGTT
>c9d90319-ec63-4347-9244-ad080b0815c5 runid=4140cbe7f7cd36a17a00b732f27dd37bd09e4380 sampleid=mariposas read=30196 ch=317 start_time=2022-11-23T14:47:32Z model_version_id=2021-05-17_dna_r9.4.1_minion_768_2f1c8637 barcode=barcode11
GCCTTGACTATATGGTTTACCTGTTCAAATACGACTCTACTCATGGTCGTTTCAAGGGAACAGTTGAGGTTCAAGGATGGTTTCCTCGTAGTAGTCTCAATGGAAACAAATCTCCTGTCTTCTGTGAAAGAGACCCTAAAATC
```

And I want to rename the reads with the first id and the barcode (last word) linked by "_".

My expect out is:

```
>e855552f-9484-4674-8fc4-d9b1f1add023_barcode06
GCTTTAACATTTAGCTATTTATGACACAGTGAAATAAAAGTAATATCTTTTTATTTTTAATTGTATTTATTAGTTACATGTTTTCACATGCATTTAACATAAATGTGATAATTTATGGGAATTACACTACTGTCAAAGTAGTT
>c9d90319-ec63-4347-9244-ad080b0815c5_barcode11
GCCTTGACTATATGGTTTACCTGTTCAAATACGACTCTACTCATGGTCGTTTCAAGGGAACAGTTGAGGTTCAAGGATGGTTTCCTCGTAGTAGTCTCAATGGAAACAAATCTCCTGTCTTCTGTGAAAGAGACCCTAAAATC
```

I'm trying with `sed` command, but I don't know if it's the best option. I don't know how to specify a number of words (first and last) with sed instead of a fixed word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` one-liner should do the trick:

```
sed 's/ .* barcode=/_/' file
```

which simply replaces the substring from the first space character to the  `barcode=` with a `_`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lpe 's{^(>\S+).*barcode=(\S+)}{$1_$2}' input.fa > output.fa
```

or change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe 's{^(>\S+).*barcode=(\S+)}{$1_$2}' input.fa
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT}` : substitute `PATTERN` with `REPLACEMENT`.
`^` : beginning of the line.
`\S+` : non-whitespace character repeated 1 or more times.
`(...)` : parentheses capture the matched pattern inside them into match variables: `$1`, `$2`, etc.
`.*` : any character repeated 0 or more times.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)